# How to provide multiple values for KeyUsage?

Tags: java, kotlin, x509certificate, bouncycastle

I have created a certificate programmatically with https://www.bouncycastle.org/ library.
The code that I have so far looks as follows:

```
fun generate(
    keyPair: KeyPair,
    hashAlgorithm: String?,
    cn: String,
    days: Long
    ): X509Certificate? {
    val now: Instant = Instant.now()
    val notBefore: Date = Date.from(now)
    val notAfter: Date = Date.from(now.plus(Duration.ofDays(days)))
    val contentSigner: ContentSigner = JcaContentSignerBuilder(hashAlgorithm).build(keyPair.private)
    val x500Name = X500Name("CN=$cn")
    val certificateBuilder: X509v3CertificateBuilder = JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder(
        x500Name,
        BigInteger.valueOf(now.toEpochMilli()),
        notBefore,
        notAfter,
        x500Name,
        keyPair.public
    )
        .addExtension(Extension.subjectKeyIdentifier, false, createSubjectKeyId(keyPair.public))
        .addExtension(Extension.authorityKeyIdentifier, false, createAuthorityKeyId(keyPair.public))
        .addExtension(Extension.basicConstraints, false, BasicConstraints(false))
        .addExtension(Extension.keyUsage, true, KeyUsage(KeyUsage.digitalSignature and KeyUsage.keyEncipherment and KeyUsage.nonRepudiation))

    return JcaX509CertificateConverter()
        .setProvider(BouncyCastleProvider()).getCertificate(certificateBuilder.build(contentSigner))
}
```

It works as expected but I would like to add multiple values to `KeyUsage` extension, namely `Digital Signature` and `Key Encipherment`.

Regarding to the documentation on https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man5/x509v3_config.html:

> Key usage is a multi-valued extension consisting of a list of names of
> the permitted key usages. The defined values are: digitalSignature,
> nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment, keyAgreement,
> keyCertSign, cRLSign, encipherOnly, and decipherOnly.

it is possible.

I tried:

```
.addExtension(Extension.keyUsage, true, KeyUsage(KeyUsage.digitalSignature and KeyUsage.keyEncipherment))
```

it shows only `Digital Signature` but the expectation is `Digital Signature, Key Encipherment`:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try bitwise OR instead of AND.